# After change of orientation viewPager is leaving space at bottom of screen

Tags: android

When I rotate the screen then CoordinatorLayout leaving white space at the bottom of screen, please help me out if somebody have solution

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/color_brand"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/NoActionBarTheme">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/linearPesanan"
                android:background="@drawable/hover_selector40ffffff"
                android:paddingLeft="-15dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scaleX="0.90"
                    android:scaleY="0.90"
                    android:src="@drawable/assets_left_arrow_white"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Pesanan"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="16sp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/color_brand"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabGravity="center"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#cccccc"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.30"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Semua pesanan"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                    android:id="@+id/semuaPesanan"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textColor="#333333"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.70"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Filter"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                    android:id="@+id/pesananFilter"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/abc_action_bar_content_inset_material"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textColor="#333333"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Image is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYpcB.png)

Comment: can you upload the images?

Comment: i think you might be somewhere putting marginBottom on the layout

Comment: @Sanoop I have three tabs out of that for two tabs it's working fine but for last tab it's giving me white space

Comment: @VinodPattanshetti check you last tab fragment layout. You might be having some margin/padding bottom in that.

Comment: @KevalPatel No there no such margin/padding bottom in my last tab .xml file for two tabs it's working fine but for last one it's not working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Whenever we load list items then list item's xml's height should be "wrap_content" if we take match_parent then it will take empty white space.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#999999"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#999999"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

   </layout>
```